# Cookies question regards Application in Chrome DevTool

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-devtools

Do you know what is the different between the left panel 3rd party domain cookies and 3rd party domain cookies under its own domain? (refer to the screenshot)
[image: example]

I expect only its own domain to be includes in and all other 3rd party domain cookies should not be there.